# Where to find information about the exact binary representation of floating point values used by avr-gcc when compiling for 8-bit processors?

Tags: c++, floating-point, avr-gcc

I need to find out the exact binary representation for `float`s and `double`s in a C++ project built with Platformio for an Atmega328 using the Arduino framework. I don't have access to the actual hardware so I can't check it myself.

The micro does not have an FPU and is 8-bit so it's pretty much all up to the compiler (or framework's libraries?) - which in this case seems to be `avr-gcc`, version 7.3. I've managed to get as far as the [`avr-gcc` documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc) telling me that by default `double` is represented the same way as a `float` but does not specify what that actually is (the IEEE standard is only mentioned for an optional  `long double`).

So, the question is kinda twofold, really. Most importantly, I need to know what representation is the float in this particular case (I strongly suspect it's IEEE 754, but could use a confirmation). And secondly, I wonder where can find this information formally, as a part of some kind of official documentation.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote reason given; it's bogus. But I am unable to help with this question.

Comment: if you don't have hardware then you can you debug your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Floating-Point Format

In any case, the floating-point format is:

IEEE-754, binary, little-endian.

In the encoded form, respective parts of the representation will occupy:

|  | 32-Bit Floating-Point | 64-Bit Floating-Point |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sign | 1 bit (31) | 1 bit (63) |
| Biased Exponent | 8 bits (30−23) | 11 bits (62−52) |
| Encoded Mantissa | 23 Bits (22−0) | 52 bits (51−0) |
| Exponent Bias | 127 | 1023 |
| sizeof | 4 | 8 |

NaNs are non-signalling.

Some of the properties are available as GCC built-in macros, for example for `float`, run

```
> echo "" | avr-gcc -xc - -E -dM | grep _FL | sort

#define __FLOAT_WORD_ORDER__ __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
...
#define __FLT_HAS_DENORM__ 1
#define __FLT_HAS_INFINITY__ 1
#define __FLT_HAS_QUIET_NAN__ 1
#define __FLT_MANT_DIG__ 24
#define __FLT_MAX_EXP__ 128
...
#define __FLT_MIN_EXP__ (-125)
#define __FLT_RADIX__ 2
#define __SIZEOF_FLOAT__ 4
```

For `double` properties, grep for `__DBL` or `DOUBLE`.

### Floating-Point Availability

- Up to and including avr-gcc v9, we have `float` = `double` = `long double` and all are 32 bits wide.
- For avr-gcc v10 onwards: The size of `double` depends on command line option `-mdouble=[32|64]`, cf. [avr-gcc command line options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AVR-Options.html). The default and availability of this option depends on configure option `--with-double=...`, cf. the [GCC configure options for the AVR backend](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html#avr). 
   Similar applies to `long double` and `-mlong-double=` resp. `--with-long-double=`.
- Floating-point libraries do not support reduced tiny cores (`-mmcu=avrtiny`).
- 64-bit floating-point support is incomplete for devices that don't support the `MUL` instruction.

### Floating-Point Implementation

- For computations on the host like constant folding, GCC uses [MPFR](https://www.mpfr.org/).
- 32-bit floating point for the AVR target is implemented as part of [AVR-LibC](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/avr-libc/), even parts you'd usually expect in libgcc.
- 64-bit floating point for the AVR target is implemented as part of [libgcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=tree;f=libgcc/config/avr), even parts you'd usually expect in libm.
- Some functions might not be 100% IEEE compliant.  For example, IEEE requires that the result of functions like `sin` is as if `sin` was computed with infinite precision and then rounded according to the selected rounding mode.  Due to efficiency considerations, some functions might return results with less precision than mandated by IEEE.

Comment: Re "For example, IEEE requires that the result of functions like sin is as if sin was computed with infinite precision and then rounded according to the selected rounding mode." Correctly-rounded math functions are a "should" provision in IEEEE-754, not a "shall" provision. So not required but recommended and optional.

Answer (score 0):

Floating-point support is done by the [libc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) of the platform if there's no hardware floating-point there. In avr-gcc I couldn't see anything about the format of `float` in the document either. To really confirm it you really need hardware or read the avr-gcc source code

But you can quickly check the floating-point constants to see if they match the IEEE-754 values or not. If yes then it's a very high chance that the format is IEEE-754. You can also check `__STDC_IEC_559__` for full IEEE-754 compliance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(void) {
#ifdef __STDC_IEC_559__
    puts("\n__STDC_IEC_559__ macro defined\n");
#else
    puts("\n__STDC_IEC_559__ macro not defined\n");
#endif

    char flt_dig = FLT_DIG; // should be 6
    char flt_mant_dig = FLT_MANT_DIG; // should be 24
    char flt_max_10_exp = FLT_MAX_10_EXP; // should be 38
    int flt_max_exp = FLT_MAX_EXP; // should be 128
    char flt_min_10_exp = FLT_MIN_10_EXP; // should be -37
    char flt_min_exp = FLT_MIN_EXP; // should be -125
    return 0;
}
```

[Compile the above code in Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:20,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:20,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:20,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:20),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Climits.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfloat.h%3E%0A%0Aint+main(void)+%7B%0A%23ifdef+__STDC_IEC_559__%0A++++puts(%22%5Cn__STDC_IEC_559__+macro+defined%5Cn%22)%3B%0A%23else%0A++++puts(%22%5Cn__STDC_IEC_559__+macro+not+defined%5Cn%22)%3B%0A%23endif%0A%0A++++char+flt_dig+%3D+FLT_DIG%3B+//+should+be+6%0A++++char+flt_mant_dig+%3D+FLT_MANT_DIG%3B+//+should+be+24%0A++++char+flt_max_10_exp+%3D+FLT_MAX_10_EXP%3B+//+should+be+38%0A++++int+flt_max_exp+%3D+FLT_MAX_EXP%3B+//+should+be+128%0A++++char+flt_min_10_exp+%3D+FLT_MIN_10_EXP%3B+//+should+be+-37%0A++++char+flt_min_exp+%3D+FLT_MIN_EXP%3B+//+should+be+-125%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:avrg1100,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc11%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27AVR+gcc+11.1.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) and check the corresponding assembly lines which have the same color as the original source. It's easy to see that the values are the same as IEEE-754 binary32 as expected. But it's not fully IEEE 754-compliant

Answer (score 0):

I wrote two test files. One for AVR (**test.c**):

```
float  test_u_float = 0.1234f, test_s_float = -0.1234f;
double test_u_double = 0.1234, test_s_double = -0.1234;
```

which was compiled for Atmega640:

```
avr-gcc -x c -mmcu=atmega640 -O0 -save-temps test.c
```

and produced this output (**test.s**):

```
    .file   "test.c"
__SP_H__ = 0x3e
__SP_L__ = 0x3d
__SREG__ = 0x3f
__tmp_reg__ = 0
__zero_reg__ = 1
    .text
.global test_u_float
    .data
    .type   test_u_float, @object
    .size   test_u_float, 4
test_u_float:
    .byte   36
    .byte   -71
    .byte   -4
    .byte   61
.global test_s_float
    .type   test_s_float, @object
    .size   test_s_float, 4
test_s_float:
    .byte   36
    .byte   -71
    .byte   -4
    .byte   -67
.global test_u_double
    .type   test_u_double, @object
    .size   test_u_double, 4
test_u_double:
    .byte   36
    .byte   -71
    .byte   -4
    .byte   61
.global test_s_double
    .type   test_s_double, @object
    .size   test_s_double, 4
test_s_double:
    .byte   36
    .byte   -71
    .byte   -4
    .byte   -67
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 11.2.0"
.global __do_copy_data
```

Also wrote and compiled a simple program for *amd64* platform:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float foo = 0.1234f, bar = -0.1234f;
  
int main(void)
{
    printf("U %08X S %08X\n", *(unsigned*)&foo, *(unsigned*)&bar);
    return 0;
}
```

which produced this:

```
U 3DFCB924 S BDFCB924
```

Converting signed bytes from **test.s** into binary shows that GCC encodes floats and doubles on *AVR* in the same format as on *AMD64*, i.e. **IEEE 754**.

Comment: Also this might be helpful: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Comment: Testing 2 values like that doesn't prove that IEEE-754 is used. What if they're just 2 lucky values that are the same in multiple formats?

Comment: If GCC used a different format (as someone suggested - 7 bits for an exponent), then entire mantissa would be shifted 1 bit left and we would see a different bit pattern. Also it makes no sense for GCC to complicate its logic by using different floating-point layout on different platforms (unless, of course, the target hardware itself uses non-standard encoding for floating-point values).

Comment: To check again, I reduced the whole test code to:

#include <math.h>
float pos = M_PI, neg = -M_PI;

and compiled it on both platforms. The result is still the same. Or, may be, M_PI is just another "lucky" number and I'm totally wrong.