# AVR-GCC (Arduino) - IEEE 754/IEC 559 compliance

Tags: c++, avr, avr-gcc

Informally, it appears AVR-GCC is IEEE 754 compliant.

In this environment, how do I verify at compile time that floats are indeed IEEE 754 compliant?  Much searching yields [informative but inconclusive data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70715474/where-to-find-information-about-the-exact-binary-representation-of-floating-poin)

`__STDC_IEC_559__` and friends return 0 even when runtime tests indicate floats are indeed compliant.  `std::numeric_limits` is unavailable.

Comment: A sec. `__STDC_IEC_559__` means conformance with some annex F in the C standard library, _not_ that "floats are IEEE 754 compliant". What makes "floats" being IEEE 754 compliant? How much compliance are you searching for? There are levels https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath . I would suspect there are no floating point exceptions on avr. `yields informative but inconclusive data` The answer you linked states "the floating-point format is: IEEE-754, binary, little-endian.". Is this inconclusive?

Comment: I'm working with someone who is implementing the dragonbox algorithm.  I call this inconclusive because something feels wrong about looking for `__AVR__` flag and calling it a day..  Thank you for your link, because that's the kind of thing I am looking for

Comment: If you think it is inconclusive, you could defined a floating point variable, print out the hexdecimal values pointed to the floating variable and verify it with online [IEEE-754 PF conversion](https://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/32bit.html) tool.

Comment: Let's not fall trap to equivocation.  Inconclusive in this context means the lack of compiler-time proof that the compiler in its current state conforms to IEEE 754